# Can I get user's public profile data on facebook using user's first name, last name and city?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, data-extraction, user-data

I am working on personality analysis of group of students at an university. I have their first name, last name, city and contact information etc.

Is there any way using facebook API I can retrieve their public profile information on facebook?

I have looked into [facebook graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) it requires user_id to retrieve public profile data. How can I get the user_id from available information (i.e. First Name, Last Name and City)?

Following will be few helpful features in personality analysis modeling-

1. HaveProfilePicture - YES/NO
2. FrequencyofPosts - Number
3. FriendsCount - Number
4. Likes, Shares etc.

Any suggestions or pointers are highly appreciated.

**EDIT-1:**

I would like add that it not an app or a system where we can get permission from user to access their profile information. It's more of data analysis work where we have data and we want include social media features.

Comment: There isn't. You need to have the user login to your app and grant permission to the app to get that information

Comment: @WizKid Thank you for response. Please see Edit-1. I hope I am making it clear.

Comment: You have to get permission from the user. You can't randomly download data from Facebook. Except scraping which you need written permission from Facebook to do

Answer (score 2):

As per current facebook API on 29th July 2016. There is no such way (using API) that you can access the user profile information without permission from user.